# Find a category, where product and coproduct correspond to multiplication and summation of reals

Tags: category-theory

To make a nice example of some rather obscure construction, I want to find a category C, equipped with a map v:ob(C)→ℝ such that product and coproduct of objects in C correspond to multiplication and summation of reals. Moreover, this mapping must not be trivial (obviously, constant mapping v(c)=0 satisfies the above condition), and cover either entire ℝ or at least non-negative reals.

Maybe there is an easy argument why such category can't exist?

Comment: It is easy to see an object cannot have an inverse respect to the coproduct unless it is initial (or dually an inverse with respect to the producr unless it is terminal).  So the best you could hope for is mapping to something like the reals greater than 1.

Comment: At the very least one has the category of finite sets with $v$ being set cardinality. For $v$ being surjective however, I do not know. I'm also unsure whether this map could be extended to one you desire.